# Real-world elements used to portray the fictional computer in Colossus: The Forbin Project (1970)

Tags: effects, colossus-the-forbin-project

The opening sequence of ["Colossus: The Forbin Project" (1970)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0064177) starts with close-ups of electronics, progressing up to a console of an IBM 1620, and eventually to a giant hall where "Forbin" (Eric Braeden) is first seen. I am curious specifically about two things:

1. Something that looks to me like a giant multi-platter disk drive (behind a tall glass enclosure)... movement can be seen (what looks to me like read/write heads seeking in and out)... is that what it is, and if so, was it actual computer equipment of the day, or a studio-built/commissioned prop?
2. The hall of "computer banks". I have no doubt that much of the "hall" is painted matte, although patterns of flashing lights can be seen, and the whole hall appears to light up in a sequence. How was that shot put together? What parts of the shot were physical props and what was artwork and/or visual effects? And for the props, what was existing equipment and what was studio-constructed? I am excluding from my question the large "console" bearing the embossed "COLOSSUS" name at the top - it's not all that mysterious what is going on there.

Comment: we are reminded by that film and others of the tremendous size of computers in those days and rather than imagining miniaturization (which by 1970 was not such a stretch) movies just imagined huge complexes of giant machines. you know a laptop today might have more computing power than existed in the entire world in 1970? not sure on this but 1960, i am pretty sure. a gig of memory would have cost much more than a billion dollars in 1960.

Comment: @releseabe and thats if a gig of memory in the entire world even existed in 1960.

Comment: yes, i am guessing maybe not since not long before IBM's president predicted the world demand was 5 mainframes. i wonder how much memory in 1970? i know that operator-assisted long-distance calls became automated which must have required a lot of computing power around that time (maybe before that time an operator would literally write something down for each LD call?).

Comment: There are a lot of early drives that were massive spinny disks, in stacks like a record player auto-changer. - see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_hard_disk_drives#1950s–1970s & the pics to the right. idk this movie so idk which type you saw. The IBM 1620 was EOL by 1970 so maybe they could pick up a bunch of bits cheap, from someone upgrading?